# Find the corresponding siblings in meta content using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The original html looks like:

```
  <meta content="A" name="citation_author"/>
  <meta content="Axxxxx" name="citation_author_institution"/>
  <meta content="Aorcid" name="citation_author_orcid"/>
  <meta content="B" name="citation_author"/>
  <meta content="Bxxx1" name="citation_author_institution"/>
  <meta content="Bxxx2" name="citation_author_institution"/>
  <meta content="C" name="citation_author"/>
  <meta content="D" name="citation_author"/>
  <meta content="Dorcid" name="citation_author_orcid">
  <meta content="E" name="citation_author"/>
  <meta content="Eyyyyy" name="citation_email"/>
```

The output results should be like this：

| name | instituion | orcid | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Axxxxx | Aorcid |  |
| B | Bxxx1; Bxxx2 |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |
| D |  | Dorcid |  |
| E |  |  | Eyyyyy |

I'm using Python 3.7.

I tried using 'find_all' to get all the names, then using find_next_sibling('meta', 'name':'xxx') to get the corresponding columns of a specific author. But just the take the example of ORCID, since authors BC dont have ORCID, the codes I wrote will return the ORCID of D.

```
AU_names = soup.find_all('meta', {'name': 'citation_author'})
for name in AU_names:
    AU_name = name.attrs['content']
    ORCID = name.find_next_sibling('meta', {'name': 'citation_author_orcid'})
    ORCID = ORCID.attrs['content'] if ORCID else ''
    print(AU_name, ORCID)
```

Could anyone help me? Thank u!

Comment: Your html is unclear. Are `C` and `D` two authors of the same article, or is `C` a separate author with no other data? And is `B` in 2 different institutions?

Comment: ABCDE are all the authors of the same article. Yes, C just has a name info that he is called C. And B has 2 different institutions.

Comment: Got it; one last (I hope) question - do `citation_author_institution`,
  `citation_author_orcid` and `citation_email` always have as their first letter the name of the author?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I just use ABCDE to clarify the relations. The actual case is like: name='Jim', institution='Oxford Uni', ORCID='https://orcid.org/1111-1111-1111-1111" (all 4 digits), email='Amy@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be an interesting question...

Try something along these lines:

```
orc = """<doc>[your html above]</doc>""" #we need to wrap the html in a root element

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

soup = bs(orc,'lxml')
targets = ["citation_author_institution","citation_author_orcid","citation_email"]
entries = []
for met in soup.select('meta[name=citation_author]'): 
    person = []
    for m in met.findAllNext():
        row  = []
        if (m.attrs['name'])=="citation_author":
            break
        else:
            row.append(m)
        person.append(row)
    if len(person)==0: #this to account for authors like C, with no data
        entry = [met.attrs['content'],'NA','NA','NA']
        entries.append(entry)
    else:
        entry = [met.attrs['content']]
        for target in targets:  
            mini_t = []
            for p in person:                
                if p[0].attrs['name']==target:
                    #mini_t.append(p[0].attrs['content']) #old version
                    mini_t.append(p[0].attrs['content']+' ')#edited version
            entry.append(mini_t)
        for tf in entry:
            if len(tf)==0: #this is to account for missing data
                tf.append('NA')
        #entry =[' '.join(tf) for tf in entry] #convert all inside lists to text - old version
        entry =[''.join(tf) for tf in entry] #edited version
        entries.append(entry)
#finally, create the dataframe           
columns = ['name','inst','orcid','email']
pd.DataFrame(entries,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
name    inst    orcid   email
0   A   Axxxxx  Aorcid  NA
1   B   Bxxx1 Bxxx2 NA  NA
2   C   NA      NA     NA
3   D   NA     Dorcid   NA
4   E   NA     NA      Eyyyyy
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! And I found a slight problem that needs to be fixed. line 22: `entry = [[met.attrs['content']]]` (Or it will mess when len(name)>1) :). Again, thank u for ur patience.

Comment: @CynthiaWang Not sure if this is the problem, but the line should be `entry = [met.attrs['content']]`, not `entry = [[met.attrs['content']]]` (that is, one less set of brackets).

Comment: You can change 'A' to 'Amy'. Base on my experience,  `entry =[' '.join(tf) for tf in entry]` this line will turn 'Amy' to 'A m y'.

Comment: @CynthiaWang I see what you're saying; see edit - look for the two lines with "#edited version".

Comment: @CynthiaWang Good to hear! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.